# How to get the ids of the column where it is 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns and i would like to do two things. Get the ids of the row where it is 1 also means True and get the ids of the row where the column goal and prof was 1.

```
Ids   prof    goal
1     1        1
2     0        1
3     0        0
4     1        1
```

I want something like this.
First get all the Ids where the prof was 1. 
Second task is get the id where prof and goal was 1.

Tried:

```
df.groupby(['prof','goal']).size()
```

Not sure how to get their ids with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean masks converting to boolean if only `1` and `0` values in data:

```
m1 = df['prof'].astype(bool)
m2 = df['goal'].astype(bool)
```

Or compare by `1`:

```
m1 = df['prof'] == 1
m2 = df['goal'] == 1

m3 = df[['prof','goal']].all(axis=1)
```

And filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if `Ids` is column:

```
a = df.loc[m1, 'Ids']

b = df.loc[m1 & m2, 'Ids']

b = df.loc[m3, 'Ids']
```

If `Ids` is index:

```
a = df.index[m1]

b = df.index[m1 & m2]

b = df.index[m3]
```

Slowier alternative is filter `index` after:

```
a = df[m1].index

b = df[m1 & m2].index

b = df[m3].index
```

Comment: @KSp - copy typo ;)

Comment: I get ids not in the column error and also the id is my index column. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you want you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ids': list(range(1, 5)),
                   'prof': [1, 0, 0, 1],
                   'goal': [1, 1, 0, 1]})
df.set_index('Ids', drop=True, inplace=True)

df[df['prof'] == 1].index
df[(df['prof'] == 1) & (df['goal'] == 1)].index
```

Comment: check my last paragraph, it is same like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation of the existing answers using `query`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df.set_index('Ids').query('prof == 1 and goal == 1').index
```

will then return

```
Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64', name='Ids')
```